# Spring Security OAuth resourceserver can only configure itself through the issuer-uri

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using docker to deploy an application with:

- an nginx container terminating SSL
- a Keycloak container
- a Spring Boot OAuth resource server.

I have the following configuration:

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://example.com/realms/petclinic
```

This works fine, however if I want to deploy the application using a self-signed SSL certificate, then the Spring Boot container can no longer connect to Keycloak through `https://`. I cannot control what certificates people will use to use the application with.

I cannot change the `issuer-uri` to the `http://` address as then the tokens will fail validation when used by the end-user, as the Keycloak host remains `https://example.com/realms/petclinic`.

I was wondering if there was an option to allow the Spring Boot OAuth `resourceserver` to always connect and configure itself with Keycloak over the local docker `http://keycloak` address?

It seems the `issuer-uri` and `resourceserver` auto-configuration are coupled together, which I don't think was the case for the Keycloak Java adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `issuer-uri` also adds an issuer validator to the JWT decoder.

You can use the `jwk-set-uri` instead (no issuer validation) or in addition to `issuer-uri` (when you want issuer validation but the OpenID config can't be fetched from the issuer URI)